# Problems with zooming feature in mobile version Magento

Tags: javascript, magento, mobile, zooming, gallery

The zooming works great on the computer, but as soon as you switch to tablet and/or mobile, it's no longer there. Any help?

Thanks

Comment: It is using a klass.min.js file, I am very new at this and am jumping in an already half built site. I just don't understand how it can be work fine but as soon as a you switch to mobile, you can't zoom anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any custom designing ? if yes then the solution could be another way ...if you are using just the magento themethen go to `admin panel->system->configuration->design(on the left side)->[ then change the package name to 'rwd']->ckick save[on the right top]`.
`rwd` stands for `responsive web design`.